# Why BufferedReader.ready() is not working when a same thread is created for second time?

Tags: java

I have three classes as below:

Class 1:

```
public class System1Class {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    while(true)   // Every 5 seconds it will create below two new threads.
    {
      System.out.println("New threads created.");
      Thread sndThreadSys1 = new Thread(new SendThreadSys1(), "SendThreadSys1");
      Thread rcvThreadSys1 = new Thread(new ReceivedThreadSys1(), "ReceivedThreadSys1");

      sndThreadSys1.start();
      rcvThreadSys1.start();

     try {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }

    }
  }
}
```

Class 2:

```
public class SendThreadSys1 implements Runnable{

public void run() {

    try {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(4000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String st = "BYE";
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(st.getBytes());
    System.setIn(is);
    ReceivedThreadSys1.br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); // refresh the br object

  }

}
```

Class 3:

```
public class ReceivedThreadSys1 implements Runnable{

public static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
public void run() {

    try{
        while(true)
        {
            while(!br.ready()) // waiting for input from console/Std i/p Stream
            {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            String s = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Print :::"+s);
            if(s.equals("BYE"))
            {
                break;  
            }
        }

        System.out.println("I am outside.");
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
  }
}
```

The First class is the main class where threads are created and it creates two new threads for every 5 seconds.

The first thread (SendThreadSys1) will stop the second thread (ReceivedThreadSys1) after every 4 seconds from its start time by sending the string "BYE" to Standard i/p stream.
In the first 4 seconds I am able type from console and the strings are printed in the console. But after new threads are created for second time in the main class (i.e. after 5 secs), 
the program is not detecting any input from console.

What could be the reason for not detecting any input from console in the second time?

Comment: I just scanned over your code really fast. But I think the problem is that you do not close the BufferedReaders. So if you create a new one, it has no access to the file because it is locked by the first reader.

Comment: where should I put br.close()?

Comment: Add a finally { br.close(); } to the try-catch in Class3. So before you leave the thread, BufferedReader will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your posted code, and it appeared to work. However, I did notice a possible multi-threading issue that might affect whether it always works on all systems, and so **may** be the problem.

In your SendThreadSys1 code, you have:

```
ReceivedThreadSys1.br = 
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

which just writes to a variable that will be used in another thread. Writes done by one thread are not automatically available for reads in another thread. I cannot see anything obvious that ensures that the quoted write to br is visible when the run method in the other thread reads it.

If you have a system on which you can reproduce the problem, I suggest making br private to ReceivedThreadSys1 and only updating and accessing it, even in ReceivedThreadSys1, through static synchronized get and set methods.

Incidentally, it should just be Thread.sleep(5000) etc. Thread.sleep is a static method and can only sleep the calling thread.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually after several test I found it is because of System.setIn(is) in the class SendThreadSys1. Seems like this line blocked the console input from the 2nd time. I dont know the reason but when I commented this line it worked. So, I removed the line System.setIn(is) and to get the same functionality I used public static boolean flag that will be accessed by both the thread. So whenever str = "BYE" then set the flag and in the other thread keep monitoring of the flag.